# CKEditor async command - manually calling afterCommandExec

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm attempting to use the async flag provided by the CKE Command definition as seen in the example [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.commandDefinition-property-async).

I have the command, which opens a jQuery UI dialog, where some data is input from the user. This part works fine. When the dialog is closed (i.e. user clicks **OK** or **Cancel**) I try to do as the CKE example shows and manually call `editor.fire("afterCommandExec")`, which results in the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'command' of undefined

It's coming from here:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_undo_plugin.js.html   (line 69)

```
if ( undoManager.enabled && event.data.command.canUndo !== false )
        undoManager.save();
```

I understand why the error is happening: no event data is being sent along with the call to `fire()`. However, their example has no event data sent either. I can manually fire the event with the command as data and it seems to work:

```
editor.fire("afterCommandExec", {
    command: editor.getCommand('link')
});
```

However, that doesn't seem like the right way to do this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? (with the error.. but at least a complete code).

Comment: It's tough because it's in a large project with a lot of libraries, but this is similar to what would be happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/leetbruh/hdhyg7hh/

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the example is a minimal code about how to use, not a real working example and that's why it might not work.

If your error comes from the Undo system, mark that your command doesn't use it with `canUndo = false` and handle yourself the addition to the undo stack instead of relying on it automatically.

Comment: It's possible you are right, I just think it's odd because the undo manager is a standard plugin that is pretty common. 

What you are suggesting would work, but I was hoping that I would be able to trigger the undo from the afterCommandExec event instead. Thanks for the input